# python how to sum together all values within a time interval in datetime64?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like:

```
 Payment_Method  DCASH_T3M  DCASH_T3M_3D  PAYPAL  Unknown  combined
 day_name                                                          
 2013-08-27              0             0       0        1         1
 2013-08-28              0             0       0        4         4
 2013-08-29              0             0       0       17        17
 2013-08-30              0             0       0        4         4
 2013-09-02              0             0       0        3         3
 2013-09-03              0             0       0        1         1
 2013-09-04              0             0       0        3         3
 2013-09-05              0             0       0        1         1
 2013-09-06              0             0       0        5         5
 2013-09-09              0             0       0        2         2
 2013-09-10              0             0       0        5         5
 2013-09-11              0             0       0       18        18
 2013-09-12              0             0       0        6         6
 2013-09-13              0             0       0       13        13
 2013-09-16              0             0       0       19        19
 .....
```

I would like to sum up all days in the same week so that I would have a new row for each week with the sum. I need also by Month

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try yet?

Comment: it's unclear if `day_name` or `Payment_Method` is your index but you want something like this `df.groupby(df.index.week).sum()`

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please post what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: So is `df.groupby(df.index.week).sum()` what you're after are your dates only for the same year?

Comment: no they are on multiple years

Comment: Then `df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.week]).sum()` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [`df.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) is all about.

As long as you have a proper time-series as an index.

Try `df.resample('W', how=sum)` for weekly, `df.resample('M', how=sum)` for monthly.